# PostgreSQL function returning a table

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, loops, plpgsql

I need to create a function that compute account sum for each branch and compare
to branch balance.

I tried to do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t3() RETURNS TABLE(bb integer, sum integer) AS $$ 
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..50 LOOP
BEGIN
SELECT bbalance FROM branch WHERE branchid = i
union
SELECT  sum(balance) FROM account WHERE branch = i;
END;
END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'm kinda confused right now... I would like it to return a table with 2 columns: one with the value of bbalance from the branch; the second one with the sum of every balance in that branch.

I need something that I can call with `select * from t3()`.

That's what I write in pgAdmin query editor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t3() RETURNS TABLE(bb integer, sum integer) AS $$ 
DECLARE
   bal integer;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN SELECT branchid FROM branch
  LOOP
    SELECT INTO bb bbalance FROM branch WHERE branchid = i;
    SELECT INTO "sum" sum(balance) FROM account WHERE branch = i;
    RETURN NEXT;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And the error is:

```
ERRORE:  variabile del ciclo sulle righe deve essere una variabile di tipo row o record o una lista di variabili scalari
LINE 5:   FOR i IN SELECT branchid FROM branch
              ^

********** Error **********

ERRORE: variabile del ciclo sulle righe deve essere una variabile di tipo row o record o una lista di variabili scalari
SQL state: 42601
Character: 119
```

Italian - translation is:
*loop variable of loop over rows must be a record or row variable or list of scalar variables.*

Comment: Run `SET lc_messages = 'C';` in your session to get English error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the table variables than `RETURN NEXT`, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t3() RETURNS TABLE(bb integer, sum integer) AS $$ 
DECLARE
   i integer;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN SELECT branchid FROM branch
  LOOP
    SELECT INTO bb bbalance FROM branch WHERE branchid = i;
    SELECT INTO "sum" sum(balance) FROM account WHERE branch = i;
    RETURN NEXT;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but really, all this can be done much more cleanly without PL/PgSQL at all as a trivial GROUP BY over a join:

```
SELECT b.branchid, b.bbalance, coalesce(sum(a.balance), 0) AS acctbalance
FROM branch b LEFT OUTER JOIN account a ON (b.branchid = a.branch)
GROUP BY b.branchid;
```

BTW, "sum" is a poor choice for a parameter name given that it's a commonly used built-in aggregate function.

Comment: I tried and it threw this:
error return next cannot have a parameter in function with out parameters

Comment: @Sanci Fixed, see above.

Comment: Now it says: loop variable of loop over rows must be a record or row variable or list of scalar variables. You're right for parameters name, i'm writing quite randomly and basically names just to test it

Comment: @Sanci Show the updated function and exact error please (as an edit to the question), comment here when done.

Comment: @Sanci Oh, stupid editing error on my part, hold on. Declared the loop var as `bal` not `i`.

Comment: Oh you're right, i could have spotted it even for myself :/
Thanks a lot man, now it works everything fine :)

Comment: @Sanci Cool. Now please delete the function you just created and do it with simple SQL as shown; it'll run hundreds of times faster (if not more). If you need a function, wrap it in a simple `sql` language function.

Comment: Ok i'll try. The fact is that i have to do it on PL/PgSQL or at least to demonstrate how to do it, but for testing i'll use the other version surely. It's just for testing concurrent transitions, i've to run that with other 2 functions and try the isolation level.